# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, carousel

I want to insert a carousel into my page. However after doing the steps beneath, the images just show one after another. However loading other aspects of Bootstrap 4 do work like cards.

1. Install bootstrap 4 with Nuget (downloads all relevant packages (jQuery,...)
2. I register the bundles:

   ```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
   {
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

       // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
       // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/charts").Include("~/Scripts/Chart.js", "~/Scripts/Chart.min.js"));

       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                 "~/Content/site.css"));
   }
   ```
3. In my `_Layout.cshtml` I load the bundle

   ```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    .
    .
    .
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
   ```
4. My view contains the code

   ```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel-slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
         <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
         <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="item active">
             <img src="~/Images/rsz_1agricultural-agriculture-berries-365839.jpg" />
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <h1> Get to know us</h1>
                 <br />
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> @Html.ActionLink("Start with it", "Contact", "Home")</button>
             </div>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="~/Images/rsz_2agriculture-beautiful-blur-1023397.jpg" />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
           <img src="~/Images/rsz_agriculture-basket-beets-533360.jpg" />
       </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
   ```
5. I start the page and get this

   [View of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6FaG.png)

Any help or suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use Bootstrap 3 Carousel markup for Bootstrap 4. For example, `item` is now `carousel-item`. [See the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#with-indicators) for the correct Bootstrap 4 structure...

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir are a hero! Many guides seem to be combining stuff, that messes everything up!